# Addressing registers in microcontrollers

Tags: c

Usually we address registers in microcontrollers in form of

```
#define REG_1 *((uword volatile far *)(0xBEEFFF))
REG_1 = 0x12345678;
```

I have four similar channels (e.g. UART channels) with equal sets of registers, but they all have different addresses. 
I would like to be able to find address of any register of any channel in a compact way.

Question: is it possible to apply something like this:

```
#define CHANNEL_0_offset 0xBEEF00
#define CHANNEL_1_offset 0xFACE00
#define REG_1            0x0000AB
*((uword volatile far *)(CHANNEL_0_offset+REG_1)) = 0x12345678;
*((uword volatile far *)(CHANNEL_1_offset+REG_1)) = 0x87654321;
```

?????

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's a basic math. What is the problem? Is it not working?

Comment: #define REG(channel, reg) *((uword volatile far**)(channel+reg)) ..... and then use: REG(CHANNEL_0, REG_1) = 0x12345678; .... dword val = REG(CHANNEL_0, REG1);

Comment: I wonder why manufacturer provide developers with such inconvenient list of separate aliases and its addresses, but not with any kind of structure/macros to approach similar channels easy.

Comment: Often register sets evolve. They start with a small list which grows from product to product. When working at this level you tend to get the raw list and that's it. Many companies have different ways of layering on top of this raw list, just like you are doing now. I love working low level personally. I wish everything was an address space and header with offsets.